# How to take input(date) and insert their value to thier "textbox" by asp.net(access database) OledbCommand

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, oledb, oledbconnection

I am working on editInfo Page and I did a Mysql command that inserts the data of the account that you logged into the site to textboxes.

All the textboxes were asp.net for example: asp:Listitem

But now I am using input date and I dont really know how to insert it.

```html
        
        <tr>
            <td class = "textstyle">
                שם פרטי:
               </td>                
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:TextBox name = "fname" ID="firstname" runat="server" placeholder = "השם הפרטי שלך"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "textstyle">
                שם משפחה:</td>
            <td class="style3">
               <asp:TextBox name = "lname" ID="lastname" runat="server" placeholder = "שם המשפחה שלך"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
                    <td class = "textstyle">
               אזור מגורים:
               </td>                
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="PlaceList" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem disable hidden>בחר אזור</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem id = "OurPlace">המרכז</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem id = "OurPlace2">השרון</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem id = "OurPlace3">הצפון</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem id = "OurPlace4">הדרום</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem id = "OurPlace5">ירושלים והסביבה</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
        <tr>
            <td class = "textstyle">
                תאריך לידה:</td>
            <td class="style3">
            <input id="date" name = "date" type="Date" min="1905-01-01" max="2019-01-01" value="2018-01-01"/>
                    </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "textstyle"">
                מין:</td>
            <td class="style3">
                    <input type = "radio" name="gender" id = "gender1" value ="זכר" /> <div class = "textstyle">זכר</div>
                    <input type = "radio" name="gender" id = "gender2" value ="נקבה" /> <div class = "textstyle">נקבה</div>
                    <input type = "radio" name="gender" id = "gender3" value ="אחר" /> <div class = "textstyle">אחר</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "textstyle">
                אימייל:</td>
            <td class="style6">
                <asp:TextBox name="email1" ID="MyEmail" runat="server" placeholder = "כתובת האימייל שלך"></asp:TextBox>
                        <tr><asp:Label ID="IsEmail" runat="server" Font-Names="arial" ForeColor="Red" Width="70px" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label></tr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "textstyle">
                סיסמה:</td>
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:TextBox type = "password" name = "password" id="pass" runat="server" placeholder = "הסיסמה שלך"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "textstyle">
              אימות סיסמה:</td>
            <td class="style3">
                <asp:TextBox type = "password" name = "passwordchecker" ID="passchecker" runat="server" placeholder = "חזור שנית"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

The EditInfo.Aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["User"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
    if ((Session["AdminMode"] == "1") || (Session["AdminMode"] == "2"))
        UserName = Session["AdminEditUser"].ToString();
    else
        UserName = Session["User"].ToString();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string connectionStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DataBase.mdb";
        OleDbConnection connectObj = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr);
        string mySql = "SELECT * from Users WHERE userName= '" + UserName + "'";
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(mySql, connectObj);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapt.Fill(ds, "users");
        DataRow row = ds.Tables["users"].Rows[0];
        pass.Text = row[1].ToString();
        passchecker.Text = row[1].ToString();
        firstname.Text = row[2].ToString();
        lastname.Text = row[3].ToString();
        MyEmail.Text = row[4].ToString();
        PlaceList.Text = row[5].ToString();
    }
}
```

[Picture of the problem - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr8Zk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Other html control id find out in code behind
Just add **runat="server"** in your Html code.

```
<tr>
            <td class = "textstyle">
                תאריך לידה:</td>
            <td class="style3">
            <input id="date" name = "date" runat="server" type="Date" min="1905-01-01" max="2019-01-01" value="2018-01-01"/>
                    </td>
        </tr>
```

Add screen shot of save value:
[image]

[image]

**.aspx page**
Add screen shot of binding value in date textbox :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script lang="JavaScript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var today = document.getElementById("hdDate").value;
            document.getElementById("date").value = today;
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input id="date" name="date" runat="server" type="Date" min="1905-01-01" max="2019-01-01" value="" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdDate" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**.Cs page code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hdDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
```

Screen shot of filled value of date textbox.
[image]

in edit mode we set the value of date using java script

Comment: .cs page you find the id like date or not?

Comment: also try with this : HtmlControl ctrl = (HtmlControl)this.FindControl("date"); Or try       var dateVal = Page.Request.Form["date"].ToString();

Comment: but its not letting me to insert into the textbox the value of it, Id = date; and i want to use date.text = dateVal; but its not working...